# The request of scrapy crawler is blocked. The request using requests library can be accessed normally. What's the reason?

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

Using the scrapy framework, I made the following strategies：
 1. Random user-agent
 2. Proxy IP pool
 3. Up to 15 second download interval,and random request interval
 4. Disable cookies
 5. Set concurrency to 8

But it doesn't work, because the response code of the first request is 500, and the response code of other requests is 500

---

Then I try to use the requests Library

1. Using the same agent pool,
2. Random user-agent
3. Concurrency is 12

It is normal to use the requests library. Its response code is 200。

What causes this ?

Comment: so you are using the Proxy IP pool with scrapy but no proxy with requests library?

Comment: no, i use the same Proxy IP pool  when using the requests library

Comment: What do you mean by concurrency 12 with the requests library? Requests is synchronous, is has no concurrency.

Comment: I used multithreading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of client side libraries / web products that can block income requests from web scraping libraries.

Usually, those tools check for common request headers sent by those scraper libraries, so it might be useful to double-check their presence

[How websites block web crawlers](http://quora.com/How-do-websites-block-web-crawlers)

Comment: Why can I use the requests library normally？

Comment: @JackDawson I would check both request headers and payloads to see if there's anything that can't identify one request as one being sent through scrappy